# Proper use of having in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm not entirely sure I'm understanding the constraints of using "having".
Down below, I'm accessing the Stack Overflow database to see the most downvoted posts in 2015, but am having trouble extracting the year.

```
select
  Title, Body, Score
From
  Posts
order by
  Score
having
  extract(YEAR from CreationDate) = 2015
;
```

Comment: `HAVING` deals with aggregates (such as `COUNT`, `SUM` or `AVERAGE`), which requires a `GROUP BY`. You're looking for a simple `WHERE Extract(Year from CreationDATE) = 2015` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `where`, not `having`:

```
select Title, Body, Score
From Posts
where extract(YEAR from CreationDate) = 2015
order by Score;
```

However, a better way to write the query is:

```
select Title, Body, Score
From Posts
where CreationDate >= '2015-01-01' and CreateDate < '2016-01-01'
order by Score;
```

This allows the query to use an index on `CreationDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain briefly on why having wouldn't work..? And apologies, as I'm still learning really, but the better way to write it, is that to save resources to make the query more efficient?

Comment: @PhilHong . . . I imagine the `having` is generating an error.  It is normally used after `group by`, and goes before `order by`, not afterwards.